# C# Auto-scanning factory

Tags: c#, reflection, design-patterns, factory

I there any patterns or internal solutions for solving next problem:

i've got interface **ImyInterface**(or some baseClass)  and Attribute **myAttribute**.
I need a factory class, that provides me functionality for searching all types with empty constructor, inheriting **ImyInterface** and marked with attribute **myAttribute**.

I wanna search in different modes: 
1) search  types in current assembly
2) search  types in all solution assemblies
3) search  types in target library (.lib or .dll)

at result I wanna see something like this:

Some sought-for type implementation:

```
[myAttribute(uniqueTypeNameOrSomethingLikeThat = "SuperClass")]
public class mySomeResource:ImyInterface
{
   mySomeResource(){...}
}
```

Factory using:

```
  myResourceFactory  factory = new myResourceFactory(typeof(ImyInterface), typeof(myAttribute));

  factory.ScanThisAssembly();
  factory.ScanDirrectory("C:\\libraries");

  var atlast = (ImyInterface)factory.Create("SuperClass");
```

I've already wrote my own solution, but I'am in  fear of "reinventing the wheel".

got any ideas/experience about this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That pattern is called [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_Control). There are about a million [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) containers solving this problem, each with their own positive and negative quirks. Pick one that you like best or roll your own if none fits your needs.